# Is it possible to generate LaTeX documents from within a lua interpreter?

Tags: luatex, lua, javascript, document-configuration

I'm curious about the possibilities LuaTeX offers. I understand LuaTeX is a sort of unified API which allows you to hook into the TeX engine and benefit from some abstractions which would make the engine easier to use and customize. This being said, can the following be done with luatex?

- Importing luatex as a `lua` "library" and generating a LaTeX document from within a `lua` interpreter or script without ever coding anything in LaTeX
- Hooking into an existing `.tex` file using a `lua` interpreter and treating its various components as objects, similar to how browser javascript interacts with HTML using the DOM.

I'd like for `lua` to steer LaTeX, and not the other way round. Perhaps my mastery of LaTeX is not sufficient, but I have the impression that there is no unified interface which facilitates working with various packages in a unified manner. Some packages even define their own syntax (like TikZ or tabular), which deviates wildly from the "lower-level" LaTeX syntax.

Am I setting myself up for disappointment if I expect `lua` to provide this "unified interface" I'm looking for? Or is this really possible?

Comment: see http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/TeX_without_TeX

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it all seems to make heavy use of `\directlua{...}`, which can only be done from within a LaTeX document. I was wondering whether I could run LuaTeX code from inside a *lua* interpreter and then generate a .tex file....

Comment: I basically want to see if there's a way to play/experiment with the objects live in a `lua` interpreter, do some introspection etc.

Comment: I also see there's an executable called `mtxlua` for ConTeXt, but then I'd have to invest time in learning ConTeXt... https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Running_Lua_Code_Externally

Comment: In ConTeXt, there is [context lua documents](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/cld-mkiv.pdf), using which you can code an entire document at the lua end.

Comment: You need a single tex document to trigger luatex (as opposed to texlua) processing, but it only needs to be one line it can \directlua to require a lua file that then has access to full typesetting features and can do it all within lua, I believe that's essentially what github.com/speedata is doing

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Exactly. https://github.com/speedata/publisher/blob/develop/src/tex/publisher.tex contains roughly only the `\directlua{}` call and everything else is done on the Lua side.